# Where to get information on failed disk?

Tags: hard-disk, devices, hardware, fdisk, smartctl

I have a disk inside my server which has failed and I'm trying to figure out which one it is. I did not make a list of all serial numbers as I should have. I plan on doing this but in the meantime, can I pull any additional information from the running system?

```
WARNING: Your hard drive is failing
Device: /dev/sdc [SAT], unable to open device
```

smartctl result:

```
$smartctl --all /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Smartctl open device: /dev/sdc failed: No such device
```

Since the disk is no longer online, is there someplace I can still query information on it?

**Update**

Grepped dmesg for sdc:

```
$dmesg | grep sdc
[   12.074540] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[   12.074542] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[   12.083407] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[   12.083410] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[   12.084143] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[   12.798801]  sdc: sdc1 sdc9
[   12.807266] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[716178.562173] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[716178.562252] sd 0:0:2:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Then grepped for those drives in fdisk:

```
$fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | egrep -i '^disk /dev+.' | grep 3.00 | sort
Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk /dev/sdd: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk /dev/sds: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
```

I only have three 3TB disks in this system and they are all online. However the last one is all the way at the bottom of the fdisk list at /dev/sds. If a disk drops out and then comes back online is it reassigned the same dev id or a new one? This might be the drive.

Comment: I would think that it's the same dev id because it's connected to the same physical socket on the mainboard. Maybe you can get more info from your disks using `hdparm -I /dev/sdc`

Comment: `hdparm -I` results in `/dev/sdc: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Usually the SATA ports on the mainboard have numbers 1,2,3. I would assume that 1 is sda, 2 sdb and so forth.

Comment: Try to do a `hdparm -I` on `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` so you might get the serial numbers from drives that are working which leaves the defective drive.

Comment: The mystery is that it was reported that `/dev/sdc` was failing. But there is  no device by that ID and all drives are online.

Answer (score 1):

If your drives have individual LEDs, you can generate some disk activity to make the LEDs light up with:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null
```

And try this on the responsive disks to find the bad disk by process of elimination.

Comment: Good answer! Although today most hard disks don't have leds already.

Comment: A lot of servers with front-panel disk slots still have some kind of indicator light.